# Запрос GQL в WebApp2

Tags: python, запрос

Есть таблицы:

```
class Table1(webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.User, ndb.Model):
    is_admin = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(default='')
    
    def __dict__(self):
        return {
            'id': self.get_id(),
            'email': self.email,
        }

class Table2(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    gcs_file = ndb.StringProperty()
    owner = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Table1)
```

Могу получить все id пользователей с `test@mail.ru`:

```
emailUser = 'test@mail.ru'
data_request = Table1.query(Table1.email == emailUser)
self.emailUser = emailUser
all_obj_table1 = []
for data in data_request:
            all_obj_table1.append({
                'id': data.__dict__()['id'],
                'is_admin': is_admin,
                '_obj_': data
            })
for data in all_obj_table1:
    print(data['id'])
```

А вот получить данные из 2ой таблицы, по данным из 1ой - не получается.

Кто работал с `webApp2`, как получить все `name` из `Table2` по `emailUser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-общем, я решил эту проблему следующим образом (конечно, код адаптирован для понимания):

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Table3(object):
    def __init__(self, emailUser, dbTable1):
        data_request = dbTable1.query(dbTable1.email == emailUser)
        self.emailUser = emailUser
        self.dbTable1 = dbTable1

        all_obj_table1= []
        for data in data_request:
            all_obj_tableUSER.append({
                'id': data.__dict__()['id']
            })

        self.all_obj_table1 = all_obj_table1
        self.idUser = int(all_obj_table1[0]['id'])

    def get_Key(self):
        return ndb.Key(self.dbTable1, self.idUser)


    def getData(self, _Table2):
        user_key = self.get_Key()
        request_table2 = _Table2.query(_Table2.owner == user_key)
        all_lst_nameTable1 = []
        for data in reverse_request_SliderPresentation:
            all_lst_nameTable1.append(data.name)
        return all_lst_nameTable1
```

Самая важная функция здесь - это `get_Key()`, т.к. она получает нужный тип данных и значение, который надо использовать в запросе для первичного ключа.